# Replace eval to call a function with in a variable namespace or outside the variable namespace

Tags: javascript, eval

I am having a variable `namespace`. From that namespace I need to call a function. I have written a function outside the variable `namespace`. If I use `window[functionName]` then that function is calling and executing.

Suppose if I place the function inside the variable namespace, then that function is not getting called. If I use `eval` then it is working. Is there any replacement of `eval` to call a function within a variable `namespace.window[funcitonName].call(args)` only executes if that function is in global.

My requirement is like this:

```js
var xxx = xxx || function($) {

  function onVehicleChange(..., functionName, ....) {
    window[functionName](this, args);
  }

  function maruthiVehicle(args) {

  }
}
```

Here I am getting function Name dynamically. Suppose my `functionName` here is `maruthiVehicle`; I am hard-coding that function here.

`window[functionName]` now become as `window[maruthiVehicle]` not calling because my `function(maruthiVehicle)` is inside the variable `namespace(XXX)`. Suppose if I put my `function(maruthiVehicle)` outside this variable `namespace(xxx)` then it works.

So `window[functionName]` only working here in `global` scope. I tried to use `eval`. `eval` is working fine when I put the function outside  or inside  the variable `namepsace`;

**I don't want to use `eval`. I want replacement of this `eval`.**

`eval(functionName + "(args)");`
Irrespective of my function placement inside the variable or outside the variable namespace my function call should get trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function testGlobalNetworkChange(xyz, $) {
    console.log("selectoris " + this.id + ',' + "mode is "
                + xyz+ ',' + "jQuery instance is " + $);
}

    var netowrk= network|| (function($) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        onNetworkChange: onNetworkChange,
        testnetworkChange: testnetworkChange
    };

    function testnetworkChange(mode, $) {
        console.log("AttributeSelector is " + this.id + ','
                    + "mode is "+ mode + ',' + "jQuery instance is " + $);
    }

    function solveFunction(functionName, context) {
        var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
        var func = namespaces.pop();
        for (var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
            context = context[namespaces[i]];
        }
        return context[func];
    }

    function OnNetworkChange(selector, functionName, xyz, $) {
        var func = solveFunction(functionName, window);
        $('#' + Selector).change(function(e) {
            func.apply(this, [xyz, $]);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

// Invoking your function to test.
network.onNetWorkChange(parameters);

Comment: You can delete your comments and **edit** your answer and add the descriptions to your comments instead to make it more clear. And mark your answer as answered.

Comment: @Sneak added as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Sneak deleted my comments also

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could structure the code like below:

```js
/* 
 * Global varibale - a namespace / place holder to keep the entities related to the application
 * This goes into the global variable - `window`
 */
vehicleNamespace = window.vehicleNamespace || {};

/* 
 *  Add functionality into that object
 */
vehicleNamespace = (function() {

  // Create a `local` function.
  var maruthiVehicle = function() {
    console.log("This is Maruthi");
  };
  
  // Return the object(s) that should be public in `vehicleNamespace`
  return {
    maruthiVehicle: maruthiVehicle
  }
})();

// call the function
window.onload = function() {
  vehicleNamespace.maruthiVehicle();
};
```

In order to call the function `dynamically`, you could use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) based on the requirements.

See the snippet below on its usage:

```js
/* 
 * Global varibale - a namespace / place holder to keep the entities related to the application
 * This goes into the global variable - `window`
 */
vehicleNamespace = window.vehicleNamespace || {};

/* 
 *  Add functionality into that object
 */
vehicleNamespace = (function() {

  var maruthiVehicle = function(input) {
    console.log(input);
  };

  var onVehicleChange = function(functionName, output) {
    // Note: You could also add more validations here to check if it is a `function`
    if (typeof functionName == 'function') {
      functionName.call(this, output);
    }
  }

  // Return the object(s) that should be public in `vehicleNamespace`
  return {
    maruthiVehicle: maruthiVehicle,
    onVehicleChange: onVehicleChange
  }
})();

// call the function
window.onload = function() {
  vehicleNamespace.maruthiVehicle("This is Maruthi");
  vehicleNamespace.onVehicleChange(vehicleNamespace.maruthiVehicle, "Selected Maruthi");
};
```

Comment: TypeError: functionName.call is not a function. it is not working

Comment: Check the `type` of the parameter using `typeof(functionName)` and make sure that it is a `function`; I have amended that to the above code.

Comment: function resolveFunction(functionName, context) {
        var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
        var func = namespaces.pop();
        for (var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
            context = context[namespaces[i]];
        }
        return context[func];
    }

Comment: var func = resolveFunction(functionName, window);
        $('#' + xxxxx).change(function(e) {
            func.apply(this, [parameter, $]);
        });